# Check if value range is in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, search

**What:** I have an array that has angles from 0 to 360, a predefined range is entered, and a periodically updating input ranging from 0 to 360. I want to check if the input is within the the predefined range of the array.

**Example**

```
array:
array[0]=100, array[1]=40, array[2]=320, array[3]=60, etc....
```

What I need to do is to see if the input lets say

```
input:
input=50;
```

is within a range of any of the values in the array

```
range:
range=25;
```

**What I need code to do:** 
lower range = input-range & upper range = input+range
if values between the lower range and upper range exist in the array output the array number.

**Completing the example:** input-range=25   &   input+range=75
so if a value between 25 & 75 exist in the array

`array[1]=40  &  array[3]=60` are within that range.

output the array key:

```
output[0]=1, output[1]=3
```

**Approach:**
Create a new nested array with the range added to and subtracted from the value in each array component. Then a for loop to check if the input is within any of the values.

**Example Solution:**

```
var nodeArray=new Array(); 
for(var i = 0; i<array.length;i++){
nodeArray[i].push(array[i]-range);
nodeArray[i].push(array[i]+range);
}

then the function to check:
for(var j=0;i<array.length;i++){

if ((input>nodeArray[j][0])&&(input<nodeArray[j][1])){
alert("within range");
}
}
```

**Problem:** I need a fast executing solution as time of execution is important to me and Im just curious if someone has a much improved idea on how to solve this problem.

**Note:** I also have not solved the fold over problem(350deg + 20 deg = 10 deg)

Comment: So this code works then, is that what you're saying?

Comment: Why don't you just sort the array in the beginning?  You can then easily check using binary search.

Comment: @Andy - It's not entirely functional, but close.I have not solved the roll over problem. I'm interested if someone has a better approach. By better I mean quicker execution.This seems like a bloated solution to me.

Comment: @AkshatSinghal how would a binary search stack up execution time wise? I didn't think to go that route because of intuition that it would be slower but this could be a very incorrect assumption.

Comment: for the fold you just need to insert modulo operations `(someangle+range)%360` that's all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I found three optimisations**

**First** : Don't use the function `length` in your loop, because the function is called each time. Declares a new variable and save the array length inside :

```
for(var j=0, arrayLength = array.length; j < arrayLength ;j++){}
```

**Second** : If you just need to know if one value is within the range, use `break` in your requirement `if` to exit the loop 'for':

```
if ((input>nodeArray[j][0])&&(input<nodeArray[j][1])){
  alert("within range");
  break;
}
```

**Third**: You can change the way to write the for loop.

```
for(var i = -array.length; i++ ;){}
```

Like that you remove one variable declaration and one operation of comparison.

Comment: Love the first one...second one wont work...I need to know every value thats in the range.